# Swapping pair of bits in a Byte

Tags: bit-manipulation

I have an arbitrary **8-bit binary** number e.g., `11101101`

I have to swap all the pair of bits like:

Before swapping: `11-10-11-01`
After swapping:  `11-01-11-10`

I was asked this in an interview !

Comment: Sorry for the first answer I gave if it confused you.  I completely read your before/after wrong.

Comment: @JamesM: Sorry, if its not evident but the question is: In a byte, pair out the bits for eg, if the byte is 10101100 then pairing the bits will look like - `10 - 10 - 11 - 00`. Now, if we swap the individual pairs, it would become - `01 - 01 - 11 - 00`. I needed the mechanism to implement the swapping

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In pseudo-code:

```
x = ((x & 0b10101010) >> 1) | ((x & 0b01010101) << 1)
```

It works by handling the low bits and high bits of each bit-pair separately and then combining the result:

- The expression `x & 0b10101010` extracts the high bit from each pair, and then `>> 1` shifts it to the low bit position.
- Similarly the expression `(x & 0b01010101) << 1` extracts the low bit from each pair and shifts it to the high bit position.
- The two parts are then combined using bitwise-OR.

Since not all languages allow you to write binary literals directly, you could write them in for example hexadecimal:

```
Binary        Hexadecimal  Decimal 
0b10101010    0xaa         170
0b01010101    0x55         85
```

Comment: Given that not all languages respect the pattern 0b..., it's probably worth noting that it is 0xAA and 0x55 in hex respectively.

Comment: @userx: +1 Yes, that is definitely worth noting. Added.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Thats awesome method !

Answer (score 6):

1. Make two bit masks, one containing all the even bits and one containing the uneven bits (`10101010` and `01010101`).
2. Use bitwise-and to filter the input into two numbers, one having all the even bits zeroed, the other having all the uneven bits zeroed.
3. Shift the number that contains only even bits one bit to the left, and the other one one bit to the right
4. Use bitwise-or to combine them back together.

Example for 16 bits (not actual code):

```
short swap_bit_pair(short i) {
    return ((i & 0101010110101010b) >> 1) | ((i & 0x0101010101010101b) << 1));
}
```

Comment: Um.. I think you mean 0xAA instead of 0x10101010 (0xAA being 10101010 in binary) and 0x55 instead of 0x01010101. Well for a byte anyways. 0xAAAA and 0x5555 respectively for a short.

Comment: Yeah, already edited the C-like pseudocode to use binary instead. The original question states 8 bits anyway, so...

Answer (score 0):

```
b = (a & 170 >> 1) | (a & 85 << 1)
```

Comment: This is completely unreadable; also, it's inefficient and even incorrect for edge cases. Dividing by two is not equivalent to a one-bit right shift for negative numbers.

Comment: same as tdammers answer but that is cleaner and explicitly binary, while you use decimal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant and flexible solution is, as others have said, to apply an 'comb' mask to both the even and odd bits seperately and then, having shifted them left and right respectively one place to combine them using bitwise or.

One other solution you may want to think about takes advantage of the relatively small size of your datatype. You can create a look up table of 256 values which is statically initialised to the values you want as output to your input:

```
const unsigned char lookup[] = { 0x02, 0x01, 0x03, 0x08, 0x0A, 0x09, 0x0B ...
```

Each value is placed in the array to represent the transformation of the index. So if you then do this:

```
unsigned char out = lookup[ 0xAA ];
```

`out` will contain `0x55`

This is more cumbersome and less flexible than the first approach (what if you want to move from 8 bits to 16?) but does have the approach that it will be measurably faster if performing a large number of these operations.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your number is `num`.

First find the even position bit:
`num & oxAAAAAAAA`

Second step find the odd position bit:
`num & ox55555555`

3rd step  change position odd position to even position bit and even position bit to odd position bit:
`Even = (num & oxAAAAAAAA)>>1`
`Odd = (num & 0x55555555)<<1`

Last step  ... `result = Even | Odd`

Print result

Answer (score -6):

I would first code it 'longhand' - that is to say in several obvious, explicit stages, and use that to validate that the unit tests I had in place were functioning correctly, and then only move to more esoteric bit manipulation solutions if I had a need for performance (and that extra performance was delivered by said improvments)

Code for people first, computers second.